# mysql: select all entries from a particular month using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database table called `POST`.
One of the fields is a timestamp, set to default to the current timestamp on the mysql server when the record is created.

I need a SQL query to extract all rows that have a timestamp within a particular month. That is, all records for March, or all records for November, etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you have to use [monthname()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

```
select * from thetable where monthname(date_field) = 'February'
```

or month(), but this function will return a number

```
select * from thetable where month(date_field) = 2
```

Comment: Neither will use an index if one exists on `POST.date`.

Comment: @OMG: how do you know that? and does an index really make sense here and if yes would that really speed up searching for a month?

Comment: OMG is correct.This is not efficient query.It wont use indexing and if you have millions of records it will parse all those.Use something like this:  select * from thetable where date_field>'2011-03-01' and date_field<'2011-04-01'  and you can easily find the start dates of two months.This will be pretty quick.

Comment: @shashwat: how do you know that?

Comment: I did this for my own project.I used month(timestamp) and it used to take 5 min on 100  millions rows.whereas timestamp>='month' and timestamp<'month' completed in seconds. You can think in this way.When you are using month(timestamp) server has to parse all rows to fetch month value.

Comment: sure but then you are restricted to a certain year

Comment: @Raffael1984 because all [functions in the WHERE clause are BLACKBOXES](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/functions/case-insensitive-search) to the database. Hence, I recommend to [write queries for continuous periods as explicit range condition.](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/dates)

Comment: @Raffael1984 Seems that I misunderstood your 'how do you know that' comment. Thought it's about index use for the queries you suggested?

Comment: I know that an index can't be used because of the function use because of testing the EXPLAIN output, and seeing that using a function vs not will not list an index as being used.  "Does an index make sense" is irrelevant - it's not good to assume that indexes are not present and you should code to assume that if they are, how to maximize their use -- not ignore the benefit of having them.  Filtering by year is a reality because it really doesn't make sense to return all posts for February from any year. It really depends on what the OP wants to use the query for, which hasn't been provided.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM POST p
 WHERE p.date BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND DATE_SUB('2011-04-01', INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```

This will use an index if one exists on `POST.date`, when using a function (IE: MONTHNAME, MONTH) on the `POST.date` column will not.

Comment: this will restrict searching to a specific year.

Comment: can you please explain you are you restricted to a specific year? date functions in php and mysql take into consideration of edge cases.

Comment: It's unrealistic to assume the OP wants values for any year (IE: are posts from 1970/etc really applicable?), besides the fact of index use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use monthname():

```
select * from post where monthname(date) = 'February'
```

Comment: `month()` returns an int from 1 to 12.

Comment: It was better with `month()`. `monthdate()` results depend on the current locale, so your query would stop working on installations with non-english locale set.