# Select all records within month and year

Tags: mysql, sql

When I tried to select records for specific month and year when I search I found half a solution

[mysql: select all entries from a particular month using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450814/mysql-select-all-entries-from-a-particular-month-using-php?answertab=oldest#tab-top%20but%20i%20want%20to%20also%20select%20%20particular%20year%20in%20racord)

```
select * 
from thetable 
where monthname(date_field) = 'February'
```

then i modify it following

```
select * 
from payments 
where monthname(date) = 'February' and EXTRACT(date )='2011';
```

but it show error what is correct way to select mounth and year
in my table i store date as     `2011-2-4`

Comment: Following on from the question you linked to, could you not use the `year()` method?

Comment: Is the `date` column of `DATE` datatype or `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that your column is not in a `Date` data type, so the best way you can do is to convert it first to `DATE` using `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Payments
WHERE   MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%c-%e')) = 'FEBRUARY' AND
        YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%c-%e')) = 2011
```

Comment: ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION ruhuna.STR_TODATE does not exist come

Comment: sorry, it should be `STR_TO_DATE`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from payments p 
where year(p.date) = 2011 and monthname(p.date) = 'February'
```